# Looking for a free monospace font with both light and heavy characters

Tags: font-recommendation, monospace

I'm developing a captcha and for this I'm looking for a font which fulfils the following needs:

- Monospace (all glyphs, not only letters)
- Basic latin characters (a-zA-Z0-9 and punctuation marks)
- Maybe additional symbols
- Maximum ~300 glyphs (small)
- Free to use in commercial web project

I'm mainly interested in **lightweight and heavy characters in the same font**. In text it would be hard to read and ugly, but for my needs I need ONE font which covers bold/heavy characters and also light ones.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Having light and heavy (regular and bold) weights in the same font file would be highly unusual, if not completely impractical. I've never seen such a font. Different weights come in different font files.

Comment: Typically when you have this sort of thing, it would be an all caps font where shift gives an alternate version. For example a clean uppercase by default and a grungy uppercase while using shift. I assume you could make one though.

Comment: @curious, oh yes one could certainly be made, but the OP is asking for a very specific one that exists already. Not sure any do exist, although I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Correct, I don't want to create a new font; but in the meantime it looks like I have to. Maybe I find a font editor which allows me to simply put characters of different fonts together into a new one (eg drag and drop glyphs I want to have). I'm on Linux, does someone know such editor?

Comment: That might help:
https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace&stylecount=3